# Show Sidebar Navigation only at Home using React-Router-Dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this solution but, How to Achieve this in V6 ?

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home">
            {' '}
            {/* Here */}
            <SideBar />
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/search">
            <Search />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/foo">
            <Foo />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As switch is gone, Routes are not allowing to wrap the element directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new v6 of react-router, you can use `Routes` component instead of `Switch`. [See the official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)
Tho have content inside `Route` you need to pass content to `element` prop.

Also `exact` is not supported anymore since there is no need for it now, the router matches that `path` directly:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <>
                {/* Here */}
                <SideBar />
                <Home />
              </>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route path="/search" element={<Search />}></Route>
          <Route path="/foo" element={<Foo />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much !

Comment: Glad i helped, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A little late. But maybe the option with "direct" injection of the sidebar will not suit you. Best practice, without SideBar excessive re-render/lifecycle:

```js
<Routes>
    <Route element={<SideBar />}
        <Route
        path="/home"
        element={<Home />}
        />
    /** ... some other routes with sidebar here ... */
    </Route>

    <Route path="/search" element={<Search />}></Route>
    <Route path="/foo" element={<Foo />}></Route>
</Routes>
```